# How do you do class library level connection strings in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to make a class library level connection string. I don't want to pass it down from the MVC layer.

I have a Presentation layer, a service layer, a Repository layer structure. I want to store the Connection string in the Repository layer so that I can use multiple presentation level layers (mvc, mobile, winforms, etc...).
Prior to .NET core I would have had an app.config file and store the connection string there. How do you do a similar thing in a .net core class library?

Comment: What's wrong with having a single point of registration in your MVC app where you wire up the dependencies?

Comment: @mason If I have a "single" point in mvc then I also need that "single" point in the Mobile and the WinForms applications. I would like my Repository to handle its own requirements

Comment: So what's wrong with adding a JSON or other config file to your repository class library that will contain the configuration, and then modifying your publish process to include this file as necessary in your builds?

Comment: @mason That is what I am looking for. I wasn't sure how .net core reads configuration files. In prior versions of .net as I mentioned you would have an app.config file and read your connection string from that and then your other "layers" wouldn't care about artifacts your repository needs. This is what I am trying to accomplish now.

Comment: I'm not saying don't use .NET Core's configuration libraries to read your configuration files. Maybe it'll work for your needs. But even if it doesn't, you can always just parse a JSON file or any other format you want. Think about what you're trying to do in simple terms: read a string from a file into memory.